# Glassfish schedule(timer) exception

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

i am trying repeat [this tutorial](http://www.hascode.com/2012/06/task-scheduling-in-java-ee-6-on-glassfish-using-the-timer-service/) on Glassfish 4 and java EE7.
So i created simple WebApp with maven in Netbeans.

I created simple class:

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class NewClass {

    @Schedule(minute = "*/1", hour = "*",persistent = false) 
    public void anyMethod() {
        System.out.println("hello "+new Date());
    }
}
```

But when i am deploing app to the server, i get this exception:

```
Info:   EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB NewClass: [java:global/WebApplication1/NewClass, java:global/WebApplication1/NewClass!NewClass]
Severe:   Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication start method
java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Timer Service is not available
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.startApplication(BaseContainer.java:3951)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.start(EjbApplication.java:163)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:497)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Severe:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Timer Service is not available
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.startApplication(BaseContainer.java:3951)
......

Severe:   Exception while loading the app
Severe:   Undeployment failed for context /test
Warning:   EJB Timer Service is not available. Timers for application with id 91511565780975616 will not be deleted
Severe:   Exception while loading the app : EJB Timer Service is not available
```

Why EJB Timer Service is not available ? 
  How can i enable it ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you are using an embedded glassfish, it might be disabled, you should try downloading a standalone glassfish and try again.

Regarding configuration you can verify the settings in the glassfish admin console, usually reachable at `http://localhost:4848` :

Following settings are relevant:

- Configurations -> server-config -> EJB Container -> EJB Timer Service tab
- Resources -> JDBC -> JDBC Connection Pools -> __TimerPool (here you can also test the connection via the Ping button)

Comment: Ok, the reason was that i've delete __TimerPool some time ago(because i did not know why it used). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue as well, but @wumbrath's answer didn't work. If that's the case - do try that answer first - delete the following files:

```
applications/ejb-timer-service-app
generated/ejb/ejb-timer-service-app
generated/jsp/ejb-timer-service-app
generated/policy/ejb-timer-service-app
generated/ejb-timer-service-app
lib/databases/ejbtimer
```

And, of course, restarting the server.

(source: http://www.cnblogs.com/endtel/p/5437765.html)

Answer (score 0):

Go to installation of glassfish:

```
mv glassfish/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/domains/domain1
rm -rf applications/ejb-timer-service-app/
rm -rf generated/ejb/ejb-timer-service-app/
rm -rf generated/jsp/ejb-timer-service-app/
rm -rf generated/policy/ejb-timer-service-app/
rm -rf generated/ejb-timer-service-app 
rm -rf lib/databases/ejbtimer/
```