# JavaEE Timer Service

Tags: java, timer, java-ee-7

I am trying to work with the Timer Service with JavaEE 7 and local GlassFish 4.1.

I wrote this simple class (I saw it in some example):

```
@Stateless
public class Tasker {

    @Schedule(second = "*", minute = "*", hour = "*")
    public void executeTask() {
        System.out.println("Task");
    }
}
```

But when I deploy the project, I get that error:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Timer Service is not available  
 ...   
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
```

I don't know why this happening.
I am very new in JavaEE and I didn't find anything helpful.

How can I make it work?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786424/glassfish-scheduletimer-exception

Comment: @SpringLearner I tried it but it didn't work. (Maybe I did something wrong because I am very new with this environment)

Comment: When I click on 'Ping' in `__TimerPool` I get error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver Could not initialize class org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling the GlashFish server and adding `persistent = false` to `@Schedule` solved the problem.